# How to select/copy text in iterm with the mouse while running the "less" command?

Tags: iterm, copy-paste

In iterm, while running the `less` command, I'm unable to select text to copy.  The mouse pointer changes from a crosshair to a circle in the middle, and I cannot click or drag text to be highlighted and copied.  How can I select text while viewing content with `less`?

I searched iTerm preferences/settings for `copy`, `select`, `pointer`, and `mouse`, but didn't find anything relevant.

Example:

```sh
$ echo foo > /tmp/myfile
$ less /tmp/myfile
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know how you managed to do this? I C&P from `less` in iTerm frequently, but have never seen or heard of this behavior... but glad to hear you got it fixed.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, thanks @Seamus.  Perhaps one of us has some non-default iTerm setting or shell environment setting that is causing the different behavior.

Comment: Yeah - `iTerm` has a **lot** of settings, and Apple has many keyboard shortcuts. I'm more doubtful about it being a shell setting - though I think there may be some that incorporate mouse behavior...  and probably much easier to find a shell configuration item.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the `option` ⌥ key (also known as the `Alt` key), and the mouse pointer will then change to allow text selection.